# Roxygen2: Inherits examples tag from another function

Tags: r, roxygen2

Example inheritance is a feature introduced in Roxygen2 v6.1.0 (See https://github.com/r-lib/roxygen2/issues/588).

But I don't find the syntax that should be use to inherit `@examples` tag from another function. I tried the following:

- `@inheritExamples FunctionName` which leads to an "unknown tag" error
- `@inherit FunctionName return examples` as explained [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/rd.html#inheriting-documentation-from-other-topics) for `details` tag but it seems to have no effect

Does anyone know the correct syntax to use to inherit such tag?

Answer (score 1):

Oups! My bad. It seems that the second answer is the good one. I had refreshment issue in my documentation generation.